# Как изменить стиль в mui checkbox на противоположный?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, mui

Есть простой компонент Checkbox с атрибутом color="primary" по умолчанию, этот атрибут добавляет цвет к фону флажка, а сам флажок прозрачный, как можно сделать наоборот?
Вот пример как есть: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а хотел бы получить что то подобное: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример первого варианта:

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-dubinsky-s3tw84?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Checkbox 
  icon={<CheckBoxOutlineBlankTwoTone color='warning' />}
  сheckedIcon={<CheckBoxTwoTone />}
/>
```

смысл в том что для CheckBox MUI нет стилей, поэтому берете иконки тут
https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/?query=CheckBox&theme=Two+tone
и раскрашиваете в нужный color взяв его тут
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/
к примеру
Т.о. в непомеченном состоянии у вас иконка CheckBoxOutlineBlankTwoTone, в помеченном CheckBoxTwoTone
Ну и цветом раскрасите в нужный

Comment: Звучит как решение, спасибо )